# AKS w Azure RBAC - Flux-Applier cluster-admin ClusterRoleBinding apparently not working

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, flux, azure-rbac

I have an AKS cluster configured with enableAzureRBAC=true

I am trying to install the ingress-nginx Helm chart through Flux

It throws the error

```
reconciliation failed: failed to get last release revision: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:nginx:flux-applier" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default": Azure does not have opinion for this user.
```

I can see that flux sets up a clusterrolebinding to make the flux-applier a cluster admin, which I have verified is in place

```
Name:         flux-applier-binding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cluster-admin
Subjects:
  Kind            Name          Namespace

  ----            ----          ---------
  ServiceAccount  flux-applier  flux-system
```

So I assume my issue is that Azure doesn't recognize this ServiceAccount and it isn't falling back to built in roles?

https://github.com/kubeguard/guard/blob/master/authz/providers/azure/rbac/checkaccessreqhelper.go

The Azure docs on Azure RBAC for AKS clearly state:

> If the identity making the request exists in Azure AD, Azure will team with Kubernetes RBAC to authorize the request. If the identity exists outside of Azure AD (i.e., a Kubernetes service account), authorization will defer to the normal Kubernetes RBAC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity

But this doesn't seem to be true? Or maybe Flux is doing something strange with ServiceAccounts? I say this because there is no flux-applier service account in the default namespace, only in the flux-system namespace. Yet if I assign cluster-admin to that "ghost" service account through Kubectl things start working.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding flux-nginx-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=nginx:flux-applier
```

I'd like to avoid having to do this though, doesn't seem like something that should be my responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

***I have created the AKS cluster configured with RABC***

***Use this link for [reference files](https://github.com/komali323/rabc-clusterbinding/tree/main)***

*Created the ClusterRole to grant the read access to secrets in any particular namespaces*

```
vi clusterrole.yaml
kubectal apply -f clusterrole.yaml
```

*I have created the role binding to grant the pod-reader with in the namespace and deployed the file*

```
vi rolebinding.yaml
kubectl apply -f rolebinding.yml
```

*Created the cluster binding role to grant the permissions to whole cluster*

```
vi clusterrolebinding.yaml
kubectl apply -f clusterrolebinding.yaml
```

*Created the rolebinding to grant the permissions in the admin cluster role to a user*

```
kubectl create rolebinding bob-admin-binding --clusterrole=admin --user=bob --namespace=namespace_name
```

*To  access the service account  in the ClusterRole use the below command*

```
kubectl create rolebinding myapp-view-binding --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=acme:myapp --namespace=namespace_name
```

*To grant the cluster role for entire cluster use the below command*

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding root-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=root
```

*I have created the namespace called nginx-ingress-controller using below command*

```
kubectl create namespace nginx-ingress-controller
```

*I have define the helm using flux*

```
vi helmrepository-bitnami.yaml
kubectl apply -f helmrepository-bitnami.yaml
```

*I have created customization in my flux repo to deploy the file*

```
vi kustomization-nginx-ingress-controller.yaml
kubectl apply -f kustomization-nginx-ingress-controller.yaml
```

*I have created the config map file*

```
vi configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml
```

*Till now I have created the helm repo into the nginx controller
into the cluster through flux*

*I have deployed the nginx ingress controller*

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get services
```

*Here I am able to see all the pods and services which i have created*

[image]

*After granting the permissions to the cluster, we have to update or create the auth reconcile permissions*
*By using the below commands it will create or update the missing fields or remove the extra permission*

```
kubectl auth reconcile -f my-rbac-rules.yaml --dry-run=client
kubectl auth reconcile -f my-rbac-rules.yaml
kubectl auth reconcile -f my-rbac-rules.yaml --remove-extra-subjects --remove-extra-permissions
```

[image]

*I have granted the particular roles to the particular Service Accounts as needed*
*We have use the below command to grant the permission for the default service account*

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-view \
      --clusterrole=view \
      --serviceaccount=my-namespace:default \
      --namespace=namespace_name
```

[image]

***Note:** If the azure doesn't recognize the service account we have to give the permissions for default service*

***For more information refer this [url](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)***